# Is it possible to mask/spoof email address while sending mail in Java

Tags: java, email

In simple word, whenever I will send mail to anyone (within same mail server) it should appears some fake email address i.e. `fakemail@gmail.com` but, when they reply to this mail, it should come to my actual email address that is `realname@gmail.com`.

**Note:** My both email addresses will use same domain name, but only difference will be fake and real username for that email. I needed for the privacy issue. So, that nobody can reply to my mail directly until I send any mail to them.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  What's preventing *anybody* from sending an email to `realname@gmail.com`?

Comment: Ok.. I mean to say.. I wanted to mask my `from` email address while sending any mail (in short)

Answer (score 3):

Ask your **mail server administrator** to setup an email forwarding for you.

This is not a Java specific question. What you are asking for is called an
[Email alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_alias), and is a standard functionality on mail servers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a fake "from:" field and a valid "reply-to:" field, but the only people that will be fooled by this are people who would not know how to send spam anyway.

Comment: It is probably only possible to fake the `From` in the message body, not the one in the SMTP envelope.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can (see below) mask the `From` field, you are giving away your email address in the `Reply-To` field, so you are still revealing your email address. (And if you weren't, it wouldn't be possible to reply.) So go with @Anony-Mousse and find a proper solution.

Now, please note that there are two "from" fields: one in the SMTP envelope and another in the message data.

It is quite uncommon for current mail servers to let you fake the SMTP from, though it may be possible if the server is using raw SMTP without authorization.

You are more likely to be allowed to send an email with a custom "From" in the message body (which is the one mail clients display, unless you look att all headers). However, the mail server may require that it matches the user you authenticated as.